# shortcut for running the simulation in Blender 2.8 instead of Alt+A?

Tags: shortcut, smoke-simulation

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwyjCfRJye4&lc=UgzdhFRMtQK8--hVNix4AaABAg), and at [1:40](https://youtu.be/IwyjCfRJye4?t=97) it presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to "run the simulation":

However, this keyboard shortcut does not work ib blender 2.8. I was wondering if you could help me know:

- what is the right keyboard shortcut for doing the above step
- how I can do this from the menus/toolbars? (if I forgot the shortcut)

If above are not possible then if there are specific tutorials replicating the above tutorial in 2.8?

Comment: Shift + Spacebar

Comment: @lemon are you sure about that? Playing the animation is just *spacebar* when using the default settings (unless you mapped the search function to spacebar).

Comment: @rjg is my setting modified? Don't think so, but? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kl0S.jpg

Comment: @lemon Just checked, it's *spacebar* with the factory settings.

Comment: @lemon it did not work. it opens [a selection box](https://i.imgur.com/xlCKJXp.jpg) with select box, cursor ... options in it.

Comment: @rig `Space` worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @rjg, ok, my bad: spacebar effectively. Thanks rjg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut is <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> to play the animation, if you're using the default Blender 2.8 or Industry Compatible keymap. In case you have mapped *Tools* or *Search* to <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>, then it's <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>.

You can check what is mapped to your spacebar in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Keymap*).

[image: Keymap]

Comment: thanks for your kind support ❤️